# Outlook Instant Search - hit and miss results

Tags: vb.net, outlook-addin

I have the below code to run an instant search from a tool I've developed that iterates through all Outlook folders and then uses the restrict method to get two counts, first the total and the second, a count of those items that are two years or older.

Once done, this is displayed to the user in a listview and the code below is supposed to do an instant search query on the selected result using the 'received' date to limit the results.

What I've found is that sometimes the instant result filters the results and in other cases it purely displays all items from within the selected folder. For example, a folder has 90 items but 5 are over 2 years old, sometimes it will show 5 (generally after the selection has been made from the listview twice) and the rest of the time the full 90 are shown.

Has anyone else come across this is and managed to resolve it?

```
Private Sub OpenOlFolder(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lvwProgress.DoubleClick
    With olApp.ActiveExplorer
        '// CLEAR SEARCH
        .ClearSearch()
        '// SWITCH TO SELECTED FOLDER
        .CurrentFolder = GetOlFolderFromPath(Me.lvwProgress.Items(Me.lvwProgress.FocusedItem.Index).SubItems(0).Text)
        '// DO SEARCH
        .Search(String.Concat("received:<", RetentionDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")), Outlook.OlSearchScope.olSearchScopeCurrentFolder)
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code I have noticed multiple dots in the single line of code. It is hard to understand where your code fails if something unexpected happens. So, breaking the chain of property and method calls is essential in troubleshooting such cases.

In the code you change the current folder by setting the `CurrentFolder` property of the `Explorer` class. It is a time-consuming operation, so it make sense to wait until it is done. For example, you may try to run the `Search` method in the [Explorer.FolderSwitch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.explorer.folderswitch) event which is fired when when the explorer goes to a new folder, either as a result of user action or through program code.

Also it make sense to do the same operation manually to make sure the filter is correct.

Comment: Thank you, all working perfectly now by adding the Explorer.FolderSwitch to the add-in events and encapsulating the search also within